# Compute engine: Error Connection refused after restart

Tags: google-compute-engine

I just checked up on one of my server to discover it stopped responding to any requests

around `2021-08-31 22:00:16.575 CEST` giving

```
Failed to connect to search.myapp.com port 443: Connection refused
```

Upon checking on my server it appears that the VM instance was restarted a day ago (docker show my main container up for only 24h).

This error screams firewall, so I double checked and I have both `allow-http` and `allow-https` firewall rules enabled for my instance.

EDIT: so I tried creating another VM from the image of this one and just running a [simple HTTP server](https://hub.docker.com/r/nginxdemos/hello/), same error, connection refused on both :80 and :443.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: If your app is running and the firewall is okay I think you did not reserved a static IP for the instance and when it was restarted it took a new IP so your domain is now pointing to the old IP. I'd suggest to reserve the ip and change the DNS to point to the new IP

Comment: I have a static IP, and it is still this one that is configured in my DNS

Comment: I tried creating a new VM, same problem, all the connections are refused

Comment: If the new VM comes from the original image, it also copies the configuration of the instance. It is recommended to use snapshot for restoration instead of instance image. 

You can also check the firewall inside the instance and not just the VPC Firewall. You might also want to check if you get any clues on the [serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output).

Comment: @AlexG I actually also tried creating another VM from zero and it is still refusing connections. I'm not sure what you mean by the firewall inside the instance, I always get redirected to the global firewall rules page

Comment: You can try to create a new project just for testing. If there is no issue on the new project, then it is more likely that the issue is on your project VPC configuration. With regards to the firewall inside the instance, I was talking about the `UFW` or `iptables` on Linux OS.

Answer (score 0):

From the problem description and all the following notes I would recommend to do the following:

1.- From inside your GCP project, you can run a connectivity test having as `source` one of the IP addresses you are using to reach your web server and as `destination`, your Servers VM instance. This test will simulate traffic and tell you where it's getting stuck. You can get a good reference in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/network-intelligence-center/docs/connectivity-tests/how-to/running-connectivity-tests#non-cloud-to-vpc).

2.- Validate if in your VPC firewall rule there is a missing or existing `Network Tag` that might be interfering traffic.

3.- Check your containers iptables and see if they are allowing incoming traffic, for that you can use command `iptables -L`.

4.- Last but not least and trying not to leave any loose ends, you can check if your VM instance is located in the right VPC that has the correct firewall rules enabled.